# SAS-use of lead function

Tags: sas, lead

Suppose the dataset has three columns

```
Date   Region   Price  
01-03    A        1
01-03    A        2
01-03    B        3
01-03    B        4
01-03    A        5
01-04    B        4
01-04    B        6
01-04    B        7
```

I try to get the lead price by date and region through following code.

```
data want;
set have;
by _ric date_l_;
do until (eof);
set have(firstobs=2 keep=price rename=(price=lagprice)) end=eof;
end;
if last.date_l_ then call missing(lagprice);
run;
```

However, the WANT only have one observations. Then I create `new_date=date` and try another code:

```
data want;
set have nobs=nobs;
  do _i = _n_ to nobs until (new_date ne Date);
  if eof1=0 then
  set have (firstobs=2 keep=price rename=(price=leadprice)) end=eof1;
  else leadprice=.;
  end;
run;
```

With this code, SAS is working slowly. So I think this code is also not appropriate. Could anyone give some suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sorting by the variables you want lead price for then set together twice:

```
data test;
length Date   Region  $12 Price 8 ; 
input Date  $ Region $   Price ;
datalines; 
    01-03    A        1
    01-03    A        2
    01-03    B        3
    01-03    B        4
    01-03    A        5
    01-04    B        4
    01-04    B        6
    01-04    B        7 
    ;
run;

** sort by vars you want lead price for **;
proc sort data = test;
    by DATE REGION;
run;

** set together twice -- once for lead price and once for all variables **;
data lead_price;
    set test;
    by DATE REGION;
    set test (firstobs = 2 keep = PRICE rename = (PRICE = LEAD_PRICE))
        test (obs = 1 drop = _ALL_);
    if last.DATE or last.REGION then do; 
        LEAD_PRICE = .;
    end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `proc expand` to generate leads on numeric variables by group. Try the following method instead:

**Step 1: Sort by Region, Date**

```
proc sort data=have;
    by Region Date;
run;
```

**Step 2: Create a new ID variable to denote observation numbers**

Because you have multiple values per date per region, we need to generate a new ID variable so that `proc expand` uses `lead` by observation number rather than by `date`.

```
data have2;
    set have;

    _ID_ = _N_;
run;
```

**Step 3: Run `proc expand` by region with the `lead` transformation**

`lead` will do exactly as it sounds. You can lead by as many values as you'd like, as long as the data supports it. In this case, we are leading by one observation.

```
proc expand data=have2
            out=want;
    by Region;
    id _ID_;
    convert Price = Lead_Price / transform=(lead 1) ;
run;
```